# RC4 encryption does not produce expected output

Tags: python, encryption, rc4-cipher

I am trying to understand how to use ARC4 encryption algorithm (just for educational purposes, I know it's not secure anymore), and I seem to be able to encrypt text but not decrypt it. Here is the very basic code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4

key = '#KCMDDC51#-890'

cipher = ARC4.new(key)
crypted = cipher.encrypt('wha frjcnvnb')
print(crypted)

notEncrypted = cipher.decrypt(crypted)
print(notEncrypted)
```

now, the encryption part outputs the following: b'\x82J\x96~r\x9e\xe2\xd7G\xa5Jz\xba'

but the decryption part doesn't output normal text, but this other jumbled up thing: 
b'qI\xa7\x97\xb7\x94XQ\x8a\xb1iu\xc1'.

why?

Comment: Because RC4 has an internal state that changes every time you encrypt/decrypt something, so you have to use a new instance for decryption.

Comment: thanks! it worked.

Comment: so, say I wanted to decrypt something from hex values that i have put in a .txt file, how would I do that? because I have tried but seems to give me the same problem as before, since I wasn't the one who encrypted the initial stream, and also I am not sure whether it's getting the right format for the input as I am reading from file, transforming the input from hex to bytes and then decrypting. Thanks!

Comment: If you have the key you should be able to decrypt the file. If the contents are hex-encoded you should decode first, then decrypt. If you're using Python3 use `crypted = bytes.fromhex(crypted)`, if using Python2 I think you can decode with `crypted = crypted.decode('hex')`.

Comment: I tried using bytes.fromhex and then decrypt with the key, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I can't do much with the given info. Could you share your code, the code that was used for encryption, if it is different and the tracebacks, if any errors occurred?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198391/discussion-between-justabeginner-and-t-m-adam).